# Error in trying to run Selenium in a Headless Linux Server (testing in Mac OS) with PyVirtualDisplay

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, selenium-webdriver, pyvirtualdisplay

I have been developing (on my Mac OSX) with Selenium Web Driver to do some scraping but I need to move the script to a Headless Linux Server.

With some research, it seems I need to use [PyVirtualDisplay](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyVirtualDisplay) to `simulate` the launching of browser for Selenium when in a Headless Server. Below is my code and the error I am getting.

Code: ([Source](http://coreygoldberg.blogspot.com/2011/06/python-headless-selenium-webdriver.html))

```
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from selenium import webdriver

display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
display.start()

# now Firefox will run in a virtual display.
# you will not see the browser.
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://www.google.com')
print browser.title
browser.quit()

display.stop()
```

Error I am getting:

```
My-MBP:learningpython neilnidhi$ python seleniumheadless.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "seleniumheadless.py", line 4, in <module>
  display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site- packages/pyvirtualdisplay/display.py", line 33, in __init__
self._obj = self.display_class(
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyvirtualdisplay/display.py", line 51, in display_class
  cls.check_installed()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyvirtualdisplay/xvfb.py", line 38, in check_installed
  ubuntu_package=PACKAGE).check_installed()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/easyprocess/__init__.py", line 209, in check_installed
  raise EasyProcessCheckInstalledError(self)
easyprocess.EasyProcessCheckInstalledError: cmd=['Xvfb', '-help']
OSError=[Errno 2] No such file or directory
Program install error!
```

Comment: If you need to run Selenium in a headless environment, you might as well use a headless browser like [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/). Selenium supports it (`browser = webdriver.PhantomJS()`).

Comment: Did not know about PhantomJS, checking it now ... thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this problem is very simple. You don't have an xserver runnning that pyvirtualdisplay could attach itself to. Try installing `xvfb` or any other `x11` server with its fonts and utils and it should just work fine. I apparently have a script to install the entire `xvfb` stack on linux though.

But as @Thomas Orozco pointed out, PhantomJS does the job pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

it works for me in linux

yum install Xvfb